# Solution to a non-linear simultaneous equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to solve the non-linear, two-variable system of equations
\begin{align*}
y-x+x^5-\frac{y^4x}{2(1+x^2)^2}-\frac{x^3}{1+y^2} &= 0 \\
-x-y+y^5-\frac{x^4y}{2(1+y^2)^2}-\frac{y^3}{1+x^2} &= 0
\end{align*}
with $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. You might notice that the second equation is *almost* obtained from the first by swapping $x$ and $y$, except for the first term whose signs are opposed. I think the only solution is the origin $x=y=0$, and this is seems to be confirmed numerically on WolframAlpha, but I'm not sure, and I don't know how to prove it. You can also write the system as
\begin{align*}
y-x+x^5+\frac{1}{4}\partial_x\left(\frac{y^4}{1+x^2}-\frac{x^4}{1+y^2}\right) &= 0 \\
-x-y+y^5-\frac{1}{4}\partial_y\left(\frac{y^4}{1+x^2}-\frac{x^4}{1+y^2}\right) &= 0
\end{align*}
Any hints/ideas?

Comment: The only solution is x=y=0 (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fkxeyiwyks).

Comment: As I said, this definitely seems true from numerical experiments, but how can I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted both equations into polynomials and put them into [Singular](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de) to find all solutions.

```
LIB "solve.lib";
ring r=0,(x,y),dp;
poly p1=2x9y2+2x9+4x7y2+2x7-4x5+2x4y3+2x4y-4x3y2-6x3+4x2y3+4x2y-xy6-xy4-2xy2-2x+2y3+2y;
poly p2=-x6y-x4y-2x3y4-4x3y2-2x3+2x2y9+4x2y7-4x2y3-2x2y-2xy4-4xy2-2x+2y9+2y7-4y5-6y3-2y;
ideal i=p1,p2;
def T=solve(i,30);
```

There are $89$ distinct solutions, but $88$ of them involve a complex number.

This shows that the last solution, $x=y=0$, is the only real solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is this library mathematically proven to yield all solutions?

Comment: @chaos Yes. Because it works with Gröbner bases and other exact polynomial root-finding schemes, it is one of the most powerful mathematical libraries around. You should give it a try.

Comment: Thank you, I was not even aware that exact polynomial root-finding algorithms existed. Is it possible to give exact expressions for all roots, or is it only possible to determine the number of real roots, which is sufficient here?

Comment: @chaos Abel-Ruffini theorem: you cannot determine exact expressions for quintic+ polynomials in the general case. Simply counting roots is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

According to Maple, the resultant of the numerators of the left sides of the two equations with respect to $y$ is
$$ 2\,{x}^{9} \left( 4096\,{x}^{80}+69632\,{x}^{78}+516096\,{x}^{76}+
2084864\,{x}^{74}+4272128\,{x}^{72}-163840\,{x}^{70}-25825280\,{x}^{68
}-65273856\,{x}^{66}-38729728\,{x}^{64}+154712064\,{x}^{62}+382149632
\,{x}^{60}+144474112\,{x}^{58}-791342976\,{x}^{56}-1359673728\,{x}^{54
}+226609664\,{x}^{52}+3532913024\,{x}^{50}+4419130368\,{x}^{48}-
672814592\,{x}^{46}-8622736384\,{x}^{44}-11440427968\,{x}^{42}-
5943181984\,{x}^{40}+2080361568\,{x}^{38}+6219084784\,{x}^{36}+
8104484032\,{x}^{34}+13320834677\,{x}^{32}+21495544525\,{x}^{30}+
25938523882\,{x}^{28}+22524511317\,{x}^{26}+14404728925\,{x}^{24}+
7384009128\,{x}^{22}+3941633218\,{x}^{20}+2832052128\,{x}^{18}+
2199851588\,{x}^{16}+1418048480\,{x}^{14}+701995632\,{x}^{12}+
263885888\,{x}^{10}+74884576\,{x}^{8}+15715584\,{x}^{6}+2310144\,{x}^{
4}+208896\,{x}^{2}+8192 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{6}
$$
The only real root of this is $x=0$, which implies $y=0$ from the first equation.

Comment: Thanks for this. How do you prove that this polynomial of order $80$ has no real roots?

Comment: With Maple's [sturm](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=sturm) command, which uses Sturm's theorem.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of this theorem. Unfortunately I can only accept one of the two answers, but I will upvote both... I don't know what the policy is here, but I will accept the other simply for providing a little more explanation in the comment, though your answer is equally flawless...